# Naming variables using dataype to describe the action

Tags: java

I was just wondering if I am breaking some sort of naming convention while naming my variables.
Let's say I have an int named numerator1. Is it wrong to name the double type conversion variable as doubleNumerator1?

Comment: It sounds like you're using something vaguely similar to [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), which is generally discouraged and regarded as redundant nowadays.

Comment: It's not wrong.  It's fine.  In fact, it's good, because it gently implies that the origin of `doubleNumerator1` is related to the variable `numerator1`.

Comment: Ahh! That's very interesting. Would something like decimalNumerator also be a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.
> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use. One-character variable names should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables. Common names for temporary variables are i, j, k, m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for characters.

This is the Naming convention for variables from Oracle.

So technically no. But variable name `numerator1` is not useful for most cases since no one reading would know what that name signifies. Rule of thumb for naming variable for me is if it's being used immediately and its use is clear I can name it something short. But if I have to use the variable for more than once or it gets used after more than 20 lines, I would name it something more meaningful.